# Manager assigning work item in Activiti

Tags: activiti

I wish to implement a work item assignment app wherein a Manager can assign items to his subordinates. Below are a few cases:
1) Escalate and reassign the item from one subordinate to another
2) Division of work load.

I see TaskService.setAssignee API, can this be used to achieve #2. But how can #1 be implemented?

Comment: You can reassign using `activiti API`too to any other subordinate.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case:
If escalation will be done on time basis, you can directly use [Timer Boundary Event](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#bpmnTimerBoundaryEvent). As the mentioned time passes, it will go directly to the next user in the flow below.

[image: Timer Boundary Event in Activiti Userguide]

Or you can call your own workload logic with Java Service Task or send e-mail to manager for new assignment.

For the second case:

TaskService.setAssignee API just takes the actual user for task, so workload division cannot be handled directly with that method. However, you can implement this by checking getAssignee() for tasks and use your workload logic in Java.